# Assembly Language MASM jumping

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm

```
   .386
   .MODEL FLAT
ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD 
Include io.h
cr     equ 0DH
Lf     equ 0AH

       .STACK 4096
       .DATA

string byte 40 Dup (?)
number dword ?
rejected byte cr, Lf, "Rejected", 0

    .code
_start:

forever: input string, 40
         atod string
         mov number, eax
         cmp number,0
         jne processing
         je finish

processing:
    cmp number,10
        jg message

    cmp number,-10
        jl message

         jmp forever

message: output rejected
         jmp forever

finish:
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

PUBLIC _start
        END
```

I'm having difficulty adjusting this assignment to meet this condition: *Make sure you jump forward to the bottom of the loop, and from there back to the top, so that every jump to top comes from exactly the same place.*

I have accomplished the task but I seem to be jumping from multiple places. How do I adjust the program to meet the condition.

Comment: Create a label after `message` (that is, for the `jmp forever`) and make your earlier `jmp forever` jump to that label instead.

Comment: `je finish` will jump to the `finish` label if the number is 0. It will fall through to `processing` otherwise. So `jne processing` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code that you have exactly **one** `jmp forever`. With a label you can jump from several places to this `jmp forever`. My suggestion:

```
processing:
         cmp number,10
         jg message

         cmp number,-10
         jl message

         jmp skipmsg

message: output rejected
skipmsg: jmp forever
```

Comment: Change the `jl message` to `jnl skipmsg`, and you can remove the `jmp skipmsg` instruction.